Installing file sizes, options concerning destination for components
I am planning to install Blender for the first time on a Windows 10 computer and was wondering if the main program can be installed on a SSD for access speed and other components installed on a HD?
In Custom Setup, if I click on the first "Blender" on the top right, the text says, "This feature requires 0K on your hard drive. It has 2 of 2 subfeatures selected. The subfeatures require 997MB on your hard drive." If I click on the second "Blender" the text says, "This feature requires 84MB on your hard drive." If I click on libraries, the text says, "This feature requires 3120KB on your hard drive." The required individual subfeataures do not add up to 997 MB.
So, my questions are 1. What is the total drive space required for Blender on a Windows computer? 2. Are the values mentioned above correct? Could you explain?
Thanks

I downloaded the portable version for Windows and unpacked it from the .zip file it comes in and current 4.3.0 version takes 992 MB (1,041,035,264 bytes) on my SSD with NTFS file system.
The same Windows version downloaded and installed to the same SSD drive with NTFS file system takes up 999 MB (1,047,879,680 bytes) in the Program Files folder and then additional 176 KB (180,224 bytes) in the %AppData%\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.3 folder where user preferences are stored. That is after fresh install.
My actual personal setup takes approximately 700MB more for add-ons and other user preferences. That will depend on what you install additionally.
If you are starting with Blender I would recommend installing everything to default locations. You could change the location of your temporary files to use a drive with more storage, because that's where autosaves will get stored:

As you can see paths for asset libraries are also configurable. It's also possible to configure Blender to use another folder for user preferences. See this answer for more details on that

So it appears that the drive space info is incorrect. Is that right?
